# Download video in the browser instead of playing it in a new tab [CORS]

Tags: javascript, browser, cors, cross-browser

I have `<a>` and inside its `href` attribute, I've got a Video URL from a 3rd-party api, when clicking on that `<a>` the browser opens a New Tab and **Play the video instead of Downloading it!**

**PROBLEM:** What I need to achieve is to download the video directly after clicking on that `<a>` instead of playing it in a New Tab and force the user to `Right Click` then choose `Save Video As` option to download it manually... Just click on `Download` and the browser starts to download that video!

**NOTE:** I am building a JavaScript App, so I need a solution in JavaScript not PHP, it has to be working on all browsers as well...

**EDIT:** I tried the [`download` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#Attributes) and it doesn't work, because it's Same-Origin Only!

**UPDATE:** The only solution I found was a +7 years old, it manipulates with the `.htaccess` file, you can check it at this [CSS Tricks Article](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/htaccess/force-files-to-download-not-open-in-browser/), it has a common issue, I can't have 2 links: `Watch Video` and `Download Video` using this solution... Many developers mentioned this bug there, but no one fixed it yet!

Comment: I updated the entire question to be more specific about my problem

Comment: does `fetch(vidURL).then(x=>x.text()).then(alert)` show some garbage, or does it error-out? If it shows garbage, we can help, and if it doesn't nobody can help you aside from the video site owners.

Comment: The actual problem is about the browser's default behavior, there is a solution using PHP, to force the browser to Download the video instead of playing it in another tab. But I am trying to find a JS Solution... *I got no problem while fetching the video URL*

Comment: Can you check this website: https://saveas.co   Actually I am building something very similar in JS not PHP as that one based on... When the user paste the FB Video URL, I am fetching it using a 3rd-party API and I get the original video download, but I can't force the browser to `Download` the video instead of opening it in a new tab!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the endpoint supports CORS, you can use [my file download lib](https://github.com/rndme/download) to save the content instead of showing it.

`download("http://distribution.bbb3d.renderfarming.net/video/mp4/bbb_sunflower_1080p_30fps_normal.mp4");`

Online Demo: http://pagedemos.com/v84rawmzntzt/output/

Comment: Great answer so far... But I've got a problem as my Video URL got too many `parameters`, this is an example [URL](https://video.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t42.9040-2/44024801_985440371627741_7820284119073423360_n.mp4?_nc_cat=108&efg=eyJ2ZW5jb2RlX3RhZyI6InN2ZV9zZCJ9&_nc_ht=video-cai1-1.xx&oh=66f2891bb31a372f883139461e7553f0&oe=5BDD21C3) ... When I tried to use your library, it doesn't seem to work with such a URL that contains parameters _(doesn't end with .mp4)_ for example.

Comment: Unfortunately returns `net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND` with blobs

Answer (score 0):

you need to set headers such as [Content-Disposition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition) from the server as follows

```
  Content-Description: File Transfer
  Content-Type: application/octet-stream
  Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="filename.jpg"
```

to allow previewing and download you might append these headers depending on query parameter for example if the url has `?download`, append these headers to tell the browser to download the file instead of viewing it.

Comment: I tried it using JavaScript by getting an instance of the `Headers` interface, then `.append()` my header, and after that, I used `.set()` to add my values... It doesn't work as well.

Comment: These headers should be set on response comming from server, what you are doing is setting the request headers.

Comment: The real problem here is that there is NO RESPONSE coming from a server, all I've is an `<a>` with `href` attribute contains a video's URL, that stored on another server.

*When I click on that Video URL, the browser opens a New Tab with a Video Player instead of Downloading the video... The question has been edited as well to be more precise.*

Comment: That's completely understandable. The problem is that I am dealing with 3rd-party websites, I don't have access to modify their servers' response to my request... Is that clear now?

Comment: Sorry, I deleted my reply before seeing your reply.

Comment: That's fine... Let me know if you can help with it!

Answer (score 0):

- You can't change the header of the 3rd party server.
- You don't want to implement a server that could proxying the request and update the header.

The only solution I can see is download and handling the content in browser js with `request` or `axios`then propose it to user (but you have to keep it in memory which might not fit for large video)

Comment: That's exactly what I did, I am sending a request and using the `Fetch API` I get the Video URL from its server. The problem is that I need the user to download that video when clicking on `Download Video` <a>... But, the default browser's behavior is that it redirects the user to a new tab and PLAY the video, I need the browser to DOWNLOAD it instead... Something like any YouTube Video Downloader!

Comment: Did you try to fetch the video url ?

Comment: What do you mean? I've already fetched the response from the API that I am using and I have the video URL as value for my <a> `href` attribute. When I click on it, it opens the video, instead of downloading it... Is that clear now?

Comment: That was clear from the begining, but I suggested to use the url from hrel and fetch it.

Comment: I replied to your newest comment above, and I really appreciate your help! :)

Answer (score 0):

As it is a Video URL from a 3rd-party api, you can resolve the problem in two ways:

1. Contact the api-provider, ask them to add the header "Content-Type: application/octet-stream".
2. Proxy the 3rd-party api, and add the header "Content-Type: application/octet-stream" in the proxy.

> Yes, the key is to set content-type header in http response.

Answer (score -1):

My best guess would be redirecting user to a separate page to force browser download the file instead of viewing it (image, video, pdf)

PHP Example using **readfile** function create a download.php file

```
<?php
$file = 'monkey.gif';

if (file_exists($file)) {
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($file).'"');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
    readfile($file);
    exit;
}
?>
```

Hope that helps.

[*Source*](http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php)