# How to force download of an aws generated file (public) in javascript

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, blob, force-download

I'm searching for the best way to force download of a generated video (~50mb) from client-side with javascript and no access to the server. 
i'm aware of [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52687330/download-video-in-the-browser-instead-of-playing-it-in-a-new-tab-cors) (which solution in my case don't work because of the cors policy). 
So my question refers to aws s3. Is there a simple way (maybe using the [aws sdk with webbrowsers](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/welcome.html#welcome_web)) to force downloads?

Or would it be simpler to use the buffer object from the Plyr videoplayer (yes there is also a player which plays this video) to make a downloadable mp4 out of it?

respectively a solution like this?

```
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
var videourl = "https://shotstack-api-stage-output.s3-ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/t63shcspnh/c7a6163b-686a-4cf0-837f-94a922a10a6c.mp4"
req.open('GET', videourl, true);
req.responseType = 'blob';

req.onload = function() {
   // Onload is triggered even on 404
   // so we need to check the status code
   if (this.status === 200) {
      var videoBlob = this.response;
      var vid = URL.createObjectURL(videoBlob); // IE10+
      // Video is now downloaded
      // and now save it
      const a = document.createElement('a');
      a.href = vid;
      a.download = filename;
      document.body.appendChild(a);
      a.click();
   }
}
req.onerror = function() {
   // Error
}

req.send();
```

Comment: What happens with the code you've shown that essentially clicks an anchor link with download attribute?